# Google app deployment on google cloud causes [Error 13]

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy a flask application with the goal of being an API using the tensorflow universal encoder model to find the similarity  of two words.

This is my run.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response, jsonify, request
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
model = hub.load(module_url)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')


@app.route('/')
def menu():
    return render_template("index.html")


def semantic(search1, search2):
    comparison = model([search1, search2])
    return np.inner(comparison[0], comparison[1])


@app.route('/<search1>/<search2>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def deploy(search1, search2):
    compare = semantic(search1, search2)
    compare = compare*100
    compare = str(compare)
    compare = compare.strip("")
    response = {
        "Semantic Similarity": compare
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return make_response(jsonify(response), 200)
    else:
        return render_template("results.html", compare=compare)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

This would be my app.yaml file

```
entrypoint: "gunicorn -b:$PORT main:app"
env: flex
runtime: python
runtime_config: 
  python_version: 3
```

And this is the error that returns when I run the command to deploy the app to a cloud build

> gcloud app deploy

I have no idea what the error means and I've tried looking at documentation and stack but the error just confuses me. Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

```
(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/semanticapi/regions/us-central1/operations/e2e4b7ca-8422-4467-a3d1-283f20b42a10 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-08-16T18:17:13.041Z81750.jf.0: Deployment Manager operation semanticapi/operation-1597601835196-5ad02a9e11fd3-f13606cb-82bdf048 errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"location: "/deployments/aef-default-20200816t180434/resources/aef-default-20200816t180434"message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/semanticapi/regions/us-central1/autoscalers\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"]
```

Comment: What are you permissions/role on the project?

Comment: Have you tested the app locally? Is it a new project or you used already existing one?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using the right GCP account and project name? Are you an owner of the project?

Comment: Yes I am the owner of the project, I have tested the app locally and it works fine. I've tried hosting it on heroku and it works, only problem is heroku costs a lot to assign a worker that doesn't cause memory errors